# Sonar JIRA Plugin : automatically create / resolve issues

Tags: jira, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I installed the JIRA plugin in Sonar for a project.
I can successfully link between issues in Sonar and issues in JIRA using Sonar's web interface and the "Link to Jira Issue" button.

The project is mainly a Java project and I use gradle to build and gradle's sonar-runner plugin to do a sonar analysis.

Is it possible to have the JIRA issues created ( or solved ) automatically whenever I'm running an analysis , so I don't have to click on "Link to Jira Issue" for every issue ( there's approx 100 issues ).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers !

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to automatically create issues in JIRA. What is your use case / process because I don't think that is worth opening a JIRA ticket for each issue (code formatting for instance)? From my point of view, you should only link important SonarQube's issues to JIRA to make them appear in your release notes for example.
Note also that there's a review workflow available in SonarQube: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Reviewing+Issues